# Video capture using Expression Encoder in WPF

Tags: wpf, video-capture, video-processing, expression-encoder

I am need to capture video and click images via camera, in My application. I am a bit new to WPF and searching on google I found that `ExpressionEncoder dll` is used to perform video captures in WPF. I also need to change brightness, Contrast, saturation of video but I did not find it in expressionencoder code.

So can anyone tell how to set Brightness,contrast,... using ExpressionEncoder Dll Or Do I need to try something else?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are using encoder dll for recording videos. please find below links.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control

http://blog.catenalogic.com/post/2009/01/08/WPF-Webcam-Control-part-2.aspx

http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/